Proper monomorphism $\Rightarrow$ Closed immersion
I am trying to understand the Gortz, Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry, proof of Corollary 12.92 and stuck at final step. I think that there seems to be a somewhat delicate issue.
First we state the Nakayama's Lemma, which is used in final step in the proof :

Nakayama's Lemma : Let $A$ be a ring with ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq A$. Let $u : N \to M$ be an $A$-module homomorphism. Assume that $M$ is finitely generated and $\mathfrak{a}$ is contained in the Jacobson radical of $A$. Then $u$ is surjective if and only if $u\otimes \operatorname{id}_{A/\mathfrak{a}} : N/\mathfrak{a}N \to M/\mathfrak{a}M$ is surjective.


Corollary 12.92. A morphism of schemes is a closed immersion if and only if it is a proper monomorphism.

Proof. Clearly a  closed immersion is proper and monomorphims. For the converse we may assume that $Y=\operatorname{Spec}A$ is affine. If $f:X\to Y$ is a proper monomorphim, the fiber $f^{-1}(y) \to \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y)$ is a monomorphism for all $y=\mathfrak{p}_y\in Y$ ( being monomorphism is stable under base change ). Thus $f^{-1}(y)$ consists of at most one point. Therefore the proper monomorphism $f:X\to Y$ is finite by Corollary 12.89 ( $f$ is finite if and only if $f$ is quasi-finite and proper ). We find $X=\operatorname{Spec}B$, where $B$ is a finite $A$-algebra. Then $f^{-1}(y) = \operatorname{Spec}B_y$ with $B_y:= B\otimes_A \kappa(y) = B\otimes_A (A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{p}_yA_{\mathfrak{p}_y}) = B/\mathfrak{m}_y B$ a finite $\kappa(y)$-algebra. Note that $B_y \cong B_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$, which is the localization of $B$ ( viewed as $A$-module ) with respect to the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_y$ ( We can exhibit explicit isomorphism ). As the diagonal $\Delta_f$ is an isomorphism ( $\because$ $f$ is monomorphism ) so that $B\otimes_A B \to B$ is isomorphism, the multiplication $B_{y} \otimes_{\kappa(y)} B_{y}=(B\otimes_A B)\otimes_A \kappa(y) \to B \otimes_A \kappa(y) = B_{y}$ is an isomorphism. And it is only possible if the vector space dimension $\dim_{\kappa(y)}B_y \le 1$. Thus $B_y = \kappa(y)$ or $B_y=0$ and we see that for all $y$, $A\to B$ is surjective modulo $\mathfrak{m}_y$. By Nakayama's lemma $A\to B$ is surjective, and $f$ is a closed immersion. QED.
I am trying to undersatnd the bold statement. My first trial for understanding is as follows. Let $\varphi : A\to B$ be the $A$-algebra map, which can be viewed as the $A$-module homomorphims. To show that $\varphi$ is surjective, it suffices to show that $\varphi_{\mathfrak{p}_y} : A_{\mathfrak{p}_y} \to B_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ is surjective for all $y\in \mathfrak{p}_y \in Y=\operatorname{Spec}A$. As argued in the proof, $B_y \cong B_{\mathfrak{p}_y} =\kappa(y)$ or $B_y = 0$. Then we have two cases :

Case 1) $B_{\mathfrak{p}_y} =0$ : In this case, $\varphi_{\mathfrak{p}_y} : A_{\mathfrak{p}_y} \to B_{\mathfrak{p}_y} =0$ is surjective.
Case 2) $B_{\mathfrak{p}_y} = \kappa(y)$ : We also want to show the surjectivity in this case. Let's view the $\varphi_{\mathfrak{p}_y} : A_{\mathfrak{p}_y} \to B_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ as $A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$-module homomorphism. Since $\mathfrak{m}_y:=\mathfrak{p}_yA_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$  is contained in the Jacobson radical of $A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ ( $\because$ $A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ is local ), by the Nakayama's Lemma above, it suffices to show that $\varphi_{\mathfrak{p}_y} \otimes \operatorname{id}_{A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_y} : \kappa(y) = A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_yA_{\mathfrak{p}_y} \to B_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y}=\kappa(y)/\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ is surjective. And this is a step that I stuck. Since $\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ is submodule of the field $\kappa(y)$, it is an ideal so that it is zero or $\kappa(y)$. If $\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y}= \kappa(y)$, then $\kappa(y)/\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y}=0$ and the surjectivity follows. But how about the case that $\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y} = (0)$? In this case we have $\varphi_{\mathfrak{p}_y} \otimes \operatorname{id}_{A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_y} : \kappa(y) \to \kappa(y)$. And homomorphism between same field may not be an isomorphism (?). How can we break through this difficulty? Can anyone help?


As I argued in the Case 2) of question, it suffices to show the surjectivity of $\psi := \varphi_{\mathfrak{p}_y} \otimes \operatorname{id}_{A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_y} : \kappa(y) = A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_yA_{\mathfrak{p}_y} \to B_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y}=\kappa(y)/\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ when $\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y} = (0)$. I think this question is about linear algebra.
Note that $\psi$ sends an element $(\frac{a}{s} + \mathfrak{m}_y) \in \kappa(y)= A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_y$ to $\frac{\varphi(a)}{s} + (0) \in B_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_yB_{\mathfrak{p}_y}=B_{\mathfrak{p}_y}  ( = \kappa(y) ) $, where $\varphi :A \to B$ is the $A$-algebra map ( Check ! ). Then note that $\psi$ is $\kappa(y)$-linear map since
for  $c:=\frac{a'}{s'} + \mathfrak{m}_y \in \kappa(y)$ and $u:=\frac{a}{s} + \mathfrak{m}_y \in \kappa(y)$,
$$ \psi ( c \cdot u)= \psi((\frac{a'}{s'}+\mathfrak{m}_y)\cdot(\frac{a}{s}+\mathfrak{m}_y)) = \psi(\frac{a'}{s'}\frac{a}{s}+\mathfrak{m}_y) = \frac{\varphi(a')}{s'}\frac{\varphi(a)}{s} = (\frac{a'}{s'}+\mathfrak{m}_y) \cdot \frac{\varphi(a)}{s}= c \cdot \psi(u).$$
where the fourth equality is by the scalar multiplication of $\kappa(y)=A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}/\mathfrak{m}_y$ on $B_{\mathfrak{p}_y} ( = \kappa(y) )$. ( I'm not entirely sure about this though. Can anyone advise? ). Since $\psi$ is injective ( being field endomorphism ), by linear algebra theorem, $\psi$ is also surjective and we are done.
